# Django unit test wait for database

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a Django command that runs a loop until the database becomes available:

```
import time

from django.db import connections
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    """Django command to pause execution until database is available"""

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """Handle the command"""
        self.stdout.write('Waiting for database...')
        db_conn = None
        while not db_conn:
            try:
                db_conn = connections['default']
            except OperationalError:
                self.stdout.write('Database unavailable, waiting 1 second...')
                time.sleep(0.1)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Database available!'))
```

I want to create unit tests for this code.

I've managed to test the database being available from the start like follows:

```
def test_wait_for_db_ready(self):
    """Test waiting for db when db is available"""

    with patch('django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler.__getitem__') as gi:
        gi.return_value = True
        call_command('wait_for_db')
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

**Is there a way to test that the command waits for the DB to be available before returning?**

So far I've tried the following, however it doesn't work as `attempt` is not accessible outside of `getitem`.

```
def test_wait_for_db(self):
    """Test waiting for db"""
    attempt = 0

    def getitem(alias):
        if attempt < 5:
            attempt += 1
            raise OperationalError()
        else:
            return True

    with patch('django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler.__getitem__') as gi:
        gi.side_effect = getitem
        call_command('wait_for_db')
        self.assertGreaterEqual(attempt, 5)
```

Comment: Why not use `global attempt`, or create a class for it ? (where methods can retrieve it using `self`, and outside using `foo.attempt`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this. The simplest approarch may just be to abandon the `getitem()` nested function and set up the side effect using a sequence of `OperationalError`s. You could then verify the number of attempts with the patched `gi` object's `call_count`. For example:

```py
def test_wait_for_db(self):
    """Test waiting for db"""

    with patch('django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler.__getitem__') as gi:
        gi.side_effect = [OperationalError] * 5 + [True]
        call_command('wait_for_db')
        self.assertGreaterEqual(gi.call_count, 5)  # Verify using the call_count
```

If you wish to keep the `getitem()` function, then I think you just need to make the `attempt` variable `nonlocal` so it can be seen inside the nested function:

```
def test_wait_for_db(self):
    """Test waiting for db"""
    attempt = 0

    def getitem(alias):
        nonlocal attempt  # Make the outer attempt variable visible
        if attempt < 5:
            attempt += 1
            raise OperationalError()
        else:
            return True

    with patch('django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler.__getitem__') as gi:
        gi.side_effect = getitem
        call_command('wait_for_db')
        self.assertGreaterEqual(attempt, 5)
```

Thirdly, and as suggested in the comments, you could create a class which has an `attempt` attribute, and use an instance of the class as the side effect:

```
def test_wait_for_db(self):
    """Test waiting for db"""

    class Getitem:
        def __init__(self):
            self.attempt = 0

        def __call__(self, item):
            if self.attempt < 5:
                self.attempt += 1
                raise OperationalError()
            else:
                return True

    with patch('django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler.__getitem__') as gi:
        getitem = Getitem()
        gi.side_effect = getitem
        call_command('wait_for_db')
        self.assertGreaterEqual(getitem.attempt, 5)  # Access the attempts from the instance
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can achieve the same in a more efficient way using the code below.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
#gives error when db isn't available
from django.test import TestCase


class CommandTests(TestCase):

    def test_wait_for_db_ready(self):
        """Test waiting for the db when db is`available"""
        with patch('django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler.__getitem__') as gi:
            gi.return_value = True
            call_command('wait_for_db')
            self.assertEqual(gi.call_count, 1)

    @patch('time.sleep', return_value=True)
    def test_wait_for_db(self, ts):
        """Test waiting for db"""
        with patch('django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler.__getitem__') as gi:
            gi.side_effect = [OperationalError] * 5 + [True]
            call_command('wait_for_db')
            self.assertEqual(gi.call_count, 6)
```

Comment: what does `gi.return_value=True` do?

Comment: @Yash
If we look at the `ConnectionHandler` class and its `__getitem__` method at this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/utils/

I believe it would return `False` if `conn` is unavailable.
Since the patched object is bound to `gi`; i.e. `__getitem__`, then by `gi.return_value = True` you are overriding its `return_value` attribute value.